# Is there any way I can control the instantiation of an attribute?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, attributes

I have some `attributes` that I want to add `dependency injection` to them.Something like this:

```
public class MyCoolAttribute : MyOtherCoolAttribute
{
    private IMyLogicComponent _logicComponent;

    public MyCoolAttribute(IMyLogicComponent logicComponent)
    {
        _logicComponent = logicComponent;
    }

    public override void DoSomething()
    {
       _logicComponent.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

Now since the .net framework instantiates the attributes, I'd like to create them with my DI container.

Is there any `AttributeFactoryCreator`? Or something equivalent?

I know that some people are against DI in attributes but I'd like to know if this is possible and not if this is the best practice or not.

Comment: No. you can't. You have to use global state if you want some service inside `Attribute`. It would be better if you can say what you're trying to achieve and why you need it? FWIW, I'm not against DI. :)

Comment: @SriramSakthivel - I've added an example for what I'm trying to accomplish. A DI strategy based on a logic component. The DI will map the correct IComponent in runtime based on my config.
I can think of lot's of work arounds...but I'd like to know if there is a nice way to interfere.

Comment: No you didn't explained why you need it, neither what you're trying to achieve. I mean why that has to be in attribute? How are you planning to use it? That part isn't clear for me. Sorry,

Comment: Lets say I have a validation attribute. One instance of my project needs to validate one way and another instance needs to validate another way.

Comment: See [this](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=98) article for a neat solution.

Comment: Don't inject dependencies into attributes; [attributes should be passive](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/13/passive-attributes).